# SQL, Select by the date BETWEEN the record rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The typical scenario/application is to search with the following data/table structure:

```
StartDate TheVersion
day1 ver1
day2 ver2
```

I.e., each *new* version number is recorded into a table with a starting date.

So for a given date, if it is BETWEEN `day1` AND `day2`, and `day1` and `day2` are the most adjacent records in the table, then `ver1` should be returned.

The problem is that I can't use the SQL BETWEEN clause because the `day1` and `day2` are actually from different rows.

How to do that? I have thought of several different ways, but none of them is not messy. Generic SQL or T-SQL appreciated. I'm on SQL Server 2008R2 BTW. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to get the version that was in effect at the time of a Given_Date. This is a nested query that first obtains the maximum StartDate on or before Given_Date, and then returns the version attached to that date:

```
SELECT
Version_Table.StartDate,
Version_Table.TheVersion
FROM
Version_Table
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT
    Max(StartDate)
    FROM
    Version_Table
    WHERE 
    StartDate <= Given_Date) maxdate on maxdate.startdate = version_table.startdate
```

Answer (score 4):

With SQL Server 2012, you can access the next (or previous) values of a row like so:

```
WITH cteWithNext AS (
  SELECT *, LEAD(StartDate) OVER (ORDER BY StartDate) EndDate
  FROM YourTable
)
SELECT n.*
  FROM cteWithNext n
  WHERE dt >= n.StartDate AND dt < n.EndDate
```

For older SQL Server versions, you can self-join on a virtual index like so:

```
WITH cteNumbered AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY StartDate) num
  FROM YourTable
)
SELECT n1.*
  FROM cteNumbered n1
  JOIN cteNumbered n2 ON n1.num+1=n2.num
  WHERE dt >= n1.StartDate AND dt < n2.StartDate
```

With these approaches you can then use the normal compare operators (or even `BETWEEN` if its semantics match your needs).